# MongoDB query $lookup with prefix

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection `rounds` and `summaries`

A record in `rounds` looks like

```
{
   "_id": "2018-04",
   "name": "Round 2018-04" 
}
```

A record in `summaries` look like

```
{
   "phase": "round:2018-04",
   "userId": NumberLong(66325),
}
```

I want to query `summaries` and lookup into `rounds`  joining based on `phase` of `summaries` into `_id` of `rounds`

**PROBLEM:** It will be pretty simple if there was no prefix of `round:` in phase.

Is there anyway to do this?

This is my code so far.

```
$cursor = $this->mongo->selectCollection('summaries')->aggregate([
            array('$match' => []),
            array(
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'rounds',
                    'localField' => 'phase',
                    'foreignField' => '_id',
                    'as' => 'roundDetail'
                ]
            ),
            array(
                '$unwind' => '$roundDetail',
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => [
                    'userId' => 1,
                    'roundDetail.name' => 1
                ]
            )
        ]);
```

MongoDB version 3.4.16

Comment: try this stage before `$lookup` stage `array(
  '$addFields' => [
    'phase' => [ '$trim' => [ '$phase', 'round:' ] ]
  ]
)` If you are using mongodb **4.0**

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet sadly thats version 4. I'm still at 3.4.16

Comment: ok then you can try this `array(
  '$addFields' => [
    'phase' => [ '$substr': [ '$phase', 6, 7 ] ]
  ]
)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet got it working with `array('$addFields' => [ 'phase' => [ '$substrBytes' => [ '$phase', 6, 7 ] ] ] ),`  Thanks alot you may post as answer i'll accept.    BTW `$substr` is deprecated and got alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`substrBytes`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/) to remove characters from the string.

```
$cursor = $this->mongo->selectCollection('summaries')->aggregate([
    array('$match' => []),
    array('$addFields' => [ 'phase' => [ '$substrBytes' => [ '$phase', 6, 7 ] ] ] ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'rounds',
            'localField' => 'phase',
            'foreignField' => '_id',
            'as' => 'roundDetail'
        ]
    ),
    array(
        '$unwind' => '$roundDetail',
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => [
            'userId' => 1,
            'roundDetail.name' => 1
        ]
    )

])
```